# corruption in java application

Tags: java, glassfish

I had a java application in production with a couple of JAX-RS endpoints served from a Glassfish server, a few months later, an error popped up in the logs like this

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: 
A MultiException has 1 exceptions.
They are:
1. org.json.JSONException: JSONObject[&quot;banks&quot;] is not a JSONArray.
root cause
A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.json.JSONException: JSONObject[&quot;banks&quot;] is not a JSONArray.
root cause
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject[&quot;banks&quot;] is not a JSONArray.
```

The problem is that the endpoint been called has nothing to do with the line throwing this error, like absolutely nothing. A colleague suggested triggering the build process again to production and see if that fixes it. It did.

My confusion is that does the Java bytecode corrupt over time? The new build is the same as the old one. I am really confused.

Comment: This could be anything ranging wrong input, programming error to hardware failure.

Comment: you need to debug what happened and stop assuming what happened, there are a huge number of possibilities but none are the bytecode become corrupt over time for no reason.

Comment: "corrupt over time?" what exactly are you asking? Do you mean that the Java Bytecode changes by itself? It definitely doesn't. The JVM may change, and 3rd party libraries may change and create new issues, but Bytecode, like any other file on a Server FS, does not change by itself

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this question in the heat of the moment, apparently an engineer who is also working on a dependency skipped the build process and deployed directly on the server which created a very interesting problem on my own end which was really impossible to debug and frustrating. Lessons learnt are

1. Bytecode does not become corrupt all by itself
2. Check for all dependencies before blaming the bytecode

Thanks guys.